# Упал сервер на Apache

Tags: apache, сервер, hosts

Здравствуйте. Я перемудрил с попыткой подключить почту и в итоге сервер напрочь упал, думаю проблема в файлах hosts и hostname.

#### `/etc/hosts`

```
 ff02::1           ip6-allnodes
 ff02::2           ip6-allrouters

 127.0.1.1         localhost mydomain.ru
 #Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
 153.233.122.219   mydomain.ru mail.mydomain.ru smtp.mail.ru
 ::1               mydomain.ru ip6-mydomain.ru ip6-loopback
```

#### `/etc/hostname`

```
 mydomain.ru
```

Comment: что подразумевает "напрочь упал"?

Comment: сайт на VPS-сервере. Стал недоступен даже по IP.

Comment: Проблема решена переустановкой системы.